# Could not find an implementation of the query pattern for source type 'System.Data.DataRow'. 'Join' not found.

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

the error is on qRow. How can I fix this problem with linq? I have tried to find an answer to this with no luck.

```
IEnumerable<DataColumn> iCols = (from i in Interlocks
        join r in Results on i.InterlockID equals r.InterlockID
        where r.StationType.Equals("RT") && r.LineID.Equals("1") && r.TestNo == 1 && r.StationID == 1
        && i.SerialNumber.Equals("C11205150001") && (r.DateTested >= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-48) && r.DateTested <= DateTime.Now)
        select new { i.SerialNumber,i.ModelNumber,r.DateTested,r.InterlockID,r.ResultID,r.ProgramDescription,r.TestStatus,r.CycleTime}).Distinct().Cast<DataColumn>();
interlock.Columns.Add("SerialNumber",Type.GetType("System.String"));
interlock.Columns.Add("ModelNumber", Type.GetType("System.String"));
interlock.Columns.Add("DateTested", Type.GetType("System.DateTime"));
interlock.Columns.Add("InterlockID", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
interlock.Columns.Add("ResultID",Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
interlock.Columns.Add("ProgramDescription",Type.GetType("System.String"));
interlock.Columns.Add("CycleTime", Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
interlock.Columns.AddRange(iCols.ToArray());
interlock.AcceptChanges();

foreach (DataRow qRow in interlock.Rows)
{
    var details = (from d in qRow
            join rd in Results_Details on d.ResultID equals rd.ResultID
            select new {d.DateTested,d.ResultID,rd.ResultNameID,rd.ResultValue}).Distinct();
```

Comment: It's a bit difficult to judge, since you didn't give the full error message and the exact location where the error occurs (_"on `qRow`"_ is actually ambiguous)... but could it be that you're missing an assembly reference (`System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll`) or a `using` directive?

Answer (score 1):

A `DataTable` is not strong typed, you need to use a [`DataRow`'s Field extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891.aspx) or cast the objects accordingly.

```
from d in qRow
join rd in Results_Details on d.Field<String>("ResultID") equals rd.ResultID
```

Also remember to add a referenceto  `System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll` and `using System.Data;` as stakx has mentioned.